# Difference between two timestamps (in days) in oracle including difference between timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a Table which has two fields with TimeStamp in Oracle DB. I have to calculate the difference between these two columns in Days including timestamp values.

```
Ex :- I have both column values as following than 
Column1 value = 07-DEC-16 11.05.24.500000000 PM 
Column2 value = 08-DEC-16 03.12.06.874000000 AM
```

Days Calculation should be shown as 1. Currently after doing search and reading many question on stackoverflow I came to know and now I am using following Query to calculate difference between these two columns

```
Select Extract( Day From Diff ) Days
From (Select B1.Column2 - B1.Column1 As Diff
From Table1 B1);
```

> This query results in calculated Days as 0 instead of 1.

I am not getting what to be done, please Guide through.
Do I need to convert it to different format? or something else ?

Comment: It is actually 0.6713... days difference so what logic are you using that this is 1 day difference? Are you just comparing the `YYYY-MM-DD`  parts and there is 1 days difference from 7th december and 8th december? Or are you doing some rounding? If so, what would happen for 1.001 days difference (would this round to 1 or 2 days difference)?

Comment: Start with your actual date difference of "+00 04:06:42.374000".  From this result, you are extracting the day value, which is correctly 0.  What is your requirement that says "days calculation should be shown as 1"?  The difference in the time stamps is just over 4 hours.  How does this become 1 day?  What if the difference of 4 hours is within the same day?

Comment: The requirement doesn't say that it should calculate exact 1 day, it says that days difference should be calculated including time difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want the difference from `2016-12-07` to `2016-12-08` (ignoring the time components) then:

```
SELECT TRUNC( column2 ) - TRUNC( column1 ) AS days
FROM   table1
```

If you want the difference rounded up to the nearest day then (ignoring the fractional seconds) you could do:

```
SELECT CEIL( CAST( column2 AS DATE ) - CAST( column1 AS date ) ) AS days
FROM   table1
```

If you want to include fractional seconds and round up to the nearest day then:

```
SELECT CEIL(
         TRUNC( column2, 'MI' )
         - TRUNC( column1, 'MI' )
         + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM column2 ) / (24*60*60)
         - EXTRACT( SECOND FROM column1 ) / (24*60*60)
       ) AS days
FROM   table1
```